# Bootstrap dropdown appears on hover...not click

Tags: html, web, bootstrap-4

I have a Bootstrap dropdown menu and it appears on hover rather than a click.  Not sure why as I haven't added any jQuery or JavaScript for it to do that.  Bootstrap 4.3.1

```
<div class="dropdown d-inline">
    <button class="btn btn-dark dropdown-toggle"
            type="button"
            id="dropdownMenuButton2"
            data-toggle="dropdown2"
            aria-haspopup="true"
            aria-expanded="false">

        <i class="fa fa-bars fa-1x"></i>
    </button>

    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-left bg-dark" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton2">
        <div class="row second_color">
            <a class="btn-ee col-12 text-white font-weight-bold mb-3" href="{{ url_for('profile.main', user_name=current_user.user_name) }}">
                <b>View Profile</b>
            </a>
            <a class="btn-ee col-12 text-white font-weight-bold mb-3" href="{{ url_for('mysubscriptions') }}">
                <b>My Rooms</b>
            </a>
            <a class="btn-ee col-12 text-white font-weight-bold mb-3" href="{{ url_for('users.account', user_name=current_user.user_name) }}">
                <b>Account</b>
            </a>
            <a class="btn-ee col-12 text-white font-weight-bold mb-3" href="{{ url_for('profileedit.viewsavedposts') }}">
                <b>Saved Posts</b>
            </a>
            <a class="btn-ee col-12 text-white font-weight-bold mb-3"  href="{{ url_for('coins.bank') }}">
                <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='favicon-16x16.png')  }}" width="20px" height="20px"><b>Tipvote Coins</b>
            </a>
            <div class="border-dark border-bottom mb-3"></div>
            <a class="btn-ee col-12 text-white font-weight-bold mb-3" href="{{ url_for('users.logout', user_name=current_user.user_name) }}">
                <b> Logout</b>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you attach `popper.js` along with JQuery & Bootstrap.js? The dropdown menu is working fine here with `bootstrap 4.3.1` & `popper.js`, as you may know already many bootstrap-components require jQuery & Popper.js including the dropdown.

[image]

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown d-inline">
                    <button class="btn btn-dark dropdown-toggle"
                            type="button"
                            id="dropdownMenuButton2"
                            data-toggle="dropdown"
                            aria-haspopup="true"
                            aria-expanded="false">

                        <i class="fa fa-bars fa-1x"></i>
                    </button>

                    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-left bg-dark" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton2">
                        <div class="row second_color">
                            <a class="btn-ee col-12 text-white font-weight-bold mb-3" href="{{ url_for('profile.main', user_name=current_user.user_name) }}">
                                <b>View Profile</b>
                            </a>
                            <a class="btn-ee col-12 text-white font-weight-bold mb-3" href="{{ url_for('mysubscriptions') }}">
                                <b>My Rooms</b>
                            </a>
                            <a class="btn-ee col-12 text-white font-weight-bold mb-3" href="{{ url_for('users.account', user_name=current_user.user_name) }}">
                                <b>Account</b>
                            </a>
                            <a class="btn-ee col-12 text-white font-weight-bold mb-3" href="{{ url_for('profileedit.viewsavedposts') }}">
                                <b>Saved Posts</b>
                            </a>
                            <a class="btn-ee col-12 text-white font-weight-bold mb-3"  href="{{ url_for('coins.bank') }}">
                                <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='favicon-16x16.png')  }}" width="20px" height="20px"><b>Tipvote Coins</b>
                            </a>
                            <div class="border-dark border-bottom mb-3"></div>
                            <a class="btn-ee col-12 text-white font-weight-bold mb-3" href="{{ url_for('users.logout', user_name=current_user.user_name) }}">
                                <b> Logout</b>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Popper was the problem!